# How to show rows where date is equal to every 7 days from a specific day

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to show every row where date_added equals '2015-02-18' and every seven days after, so '2015-02-25' and '2015-03-04' etc..

here's what I have so far

```
select * from table 
    where ((to_char(date_added, 'j')) / 
    ((select to_char(d,'j') from (select date '2015-02-18' d from dual)))) = 1
```

That gets me the first desired date, however I'm stuck as to how to express it to show the next 7 days as a step additive function.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is with `mod()`:

```
select *
from table
where mod(date_added - date '2015-02-18', 7) = 0;
```

Note:  this assumes that the dates have no time component.  If they do, then use `trunc()` to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

I like Gordon's "mod()" solution but he's missing part of the requested solution.

In this case, I have a "calendar" table that includes a series of dates:

http://www.perpendulum.com/2012/06/calendar-table-script-for-oracle/

```
select *
  from calendar
  where date_time_start >= to_date('01-Jan-2013') 
    and mod(trunc(date_time_start) - to_date('01-Jan-2013'), 7) = 0;
```

Per the original question, you want records where the dates are equal to a given date and every seven days thereafter.